# How to hide StackLayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visibility, stacklayout

I'm trying to hide `StackLayout` called `InfoStackLayout` after my config is downloaded, displaying information label for 5s,
but after hiding `Infostack` in code, my `Grid` in `ContentPage` doesn't refresh the view and leaves empty space. (the `InfoStackLayout` is invisible but still reserves the space)
Even worse, buttons in `ButtonsStack` doesn't respond correctly to clicked events.
After locking and unlocking phone everything works as it should.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" VerticalOptions="Fill" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <StackLayout x:Name="InfoStackLayout" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label x:Name="InfoLabel" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Font="18" />
    <Image x:Name="GetConfig" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Source="loading.png" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32">
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ReloadConfig_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout x:Name="ButtonsStack" Grid.Row="1">
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

```cs
InfoLabel.Text = "Download Config";
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await InfoStackLayout.FadeTo(0);
        InfoStackLayout.IsVisible = false;
        InfoStackLayout.HeightRequest = 0;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Use YourViewOrLayout.ForceLayout(); when you are showing/hiding.

Comment: Any update to the UI must be done on the main thread. Wrap the hiding logic in InvokeOnMainThread method.

Comment: @Shan Thank you! Replacing Task.Factory.StartNew with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread done the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Shan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032316/shan) answer was the best solution. Just replacing Task.Factory.StartNew with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread do the trick.